# jquery change function on dropdown value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a dropdown in my view to which i want to apply jquery(ajax onChange value). So that  JSon data passed for the selected value by controller action rendered over the same view by replacing some id of that view
**Dropdown**

```
<div><select id="package_master" name="package_master"><option value="">
--select package--</option>
<option value="1">JPMC Package1</option>
<option value="2">JPMC Package 2</option>
<option value="3">JPMC Package1</option>
<option value="5">Select Package</option>
<option value="6">Select Package</option>
</select></div>
```

What i am presently doing is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { //$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#package_master").change(function () {
        var value = $('#package_master').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: "@Url.Content("~/Test/getPackageDetails/")",
        data: "packageID="+value,
       success: function(data){//here i want to Replace come id with json data passed by action
</script>
```

url is `url: "@Url.Content("~/Test/getPackageDetails/")",`

Complete Above script
**Updated:**
I used following script to accomplish my task which is working fine too, but data is displayed in array format like ["abc","xyz"]
Now here i need help to format json data in row format i.e 1 row for each array element like 
abc
xyz

`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () { //$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#package_master").change(function () {
        var value = $('#package_master').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: "@Url.Content("~/Test/getPackageDetails/")",
        data: "packageID="+value,

      success: function(data){

        $("#packageDetails").html(JSON.stringify(data));

        },
        error: function(data){
        alert("Request couldn't be processed. Please try again later. the reason "+data);
        }
        });

    });
});
```

`

Comment: Yup true . I tried a lot to explain my asked context but fails everytime

Comment: Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: Sure. Commonly, questions have a Question mark **'?'**. What is your question here?

Comment: Thanks roXon i'll take care of it in future. My question is to "complete above script" to replace some view id(say <div id="displayJsonData"/) with json data on sucess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { //$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#package_master").change(function () {
        var value = $('#package_master').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",

        url: "@Url.Content("~/Test/getPackageDetails/")",
        data: "packageID="+value,
       success: function(data){
      data = $.map(data, function (item, a)
      {
      return " "+item+ "<br>";
      });
      $("#packageDetails").html(data.join(""));

       },

        error: function(data){
        alert("Request couldn't be processed. Please try again later. the reason        "+data);
        }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#package_master").change(function () {
            var data = { packageID: $(this).val() }
            $.post("url", data, function (backdata, status) {
                // callback, do something
            }, "json");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Nice and simple. +1. Just missing a semicolon in line 3

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax function has an option: `dataType: "json"`

Since you are using `JSON.stringify(data)` you need this parameter as `dataType: "text"`

So there's no need for `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Comment: try jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",dataType: "json",.... });  without JSON.stringify

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () { $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#package_master").change(function () {
        var packageID = $('#package_master').val();

        $.post("@Url.Content("~/Test/getPackageDetails/")", {packageID : packageID},         function (data) {
      $("#packageDetails").html("");
       $.each(data,function(i,field){
       $("#packageDetails").append(i+1+" "+field+"<br/>");
       });

        }, "json");
     }); 
   });
```

Alternatively you can use

```
$("#packageDetails").$(selector).load(url,data,function(response,status,xhr))
```

for other solutions, [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp). And I'd recommend to avoid using `$.ajax` if you have some alt.

Comment: But doing this i'll append returned data to previous data(returned for previous value change) (Appends content to the HTML of selected elements). i.e if i change dropdown value twice then packageDetails i'll hold data for both value change. Need Solution

Comment: @dhiraj and gimme brk there always a better way to do things. My way to do this is :: add $("#packageDetails").html(""); this line just above each statement. This will provide empty packageDetails for each loop

Comment: additionally you can use replaceall() also